# ¿Cómo evitar que los elementos de mi aplicación se encimen?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Bueno tengo un pequeño problema con mi aplicación.
Tengo mi siguiente layout:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero a la hora de probarlo obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:text="Por favor seleccione la clase de usuario."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:id="@+id/TituloClaseUsuario"
    tools:text="Por favor seleccione la clase de usuario."
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:text="Personal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/Personal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TituloClaseUsuario"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EOI"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/EOI" />

<TextView
    android:text="Por favor seleccione su fecha de nacimiento."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/FechaNacimiento"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Personal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<CheckBox
    android:text="Empresa, Organización o Institución."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EOI"
    tools:text="Empresa, Organización o Institución."
    android:layout_below="@+id/FechaNacimiento"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LNL"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/LNL"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:text="Lugar, Negocio o Local."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LNL"
    tools:text="Lugar, Negocio o Local."
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Siguiente"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TituloClaseUsuario"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/TituloClaseUsuario"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_siguiente"
    android:id="@+id/Siguiente"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Todo eso no lo tienes dentro de un `LinearLayout` o `RelativeLayout`?

Se los he agregado, prueba y si tienes errores puedes editar tu pregunta mostrando que salió mal.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="16dp">

  <TextView
      android:text="Por favor seleccione la clase de usuario."
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
      android:id="@+id/TituloClaseUsuario"
      tools:text="Por favor seleccione la clase de usuario."
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:textStyle="normal|bold"
      android:textSize="18dp" />

 <CheckBox
      android:text="Personal"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
      android:id="@+id/Personal"
      android:layout_below="@+id/TituloClaseUsuario"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EOI"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/EOI" />

 <TextView
      android:text="Por favor seleccione su fecha de nacimiento."
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/FechaNacimiento"
      android:textStyle="normal|bold"
      android:textSize="18dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/Personal"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
      android:textAlignment="center" />

<CheckBox
    android:text="Empresa, Organización o Institución."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/EOI"
    tools:text="Empresa, Organización o Institución."
    android:layout_below="@+id/FechaNacimiento"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LNL"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/LNL"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:text="Lugar, Negocio o Local."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LNL"
    tools:text="Lugar, Negocio o Local."
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Siguiente"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TituloClaseUsuario"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/TituloClaseUsuario"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp" />

   <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_siguiente"
      android:id="@+id/Siguiente"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:cropToPadding="false"
      android:elevation="0dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Si lo tengo dentro de un relative layout, no se porque no se mostró cuando lo pegué dentro del campo de código...

Comment: prueba lo que te puse y me dices, mas bien se me hace un problema de tamaños de pantallas, revisa este link https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html?hl=es